# Creating Style Trigger in code behind, only one of 2 setters is working

Tags: wpf, triggers, binding, code-behind

The BorderThicknessProperty is being applied correctly, but the ForeGroundProperty is not. I have tried swapping positions of the setters, thinking maybe only the first was being applied. I have tried a couple of other properties and none have work except BorderThickness. I am guessing I need to get to the Textblock of the Content, but I don't know how I would do that.

```
var foregroundSetter = new Setter()
{
 Property = Button.ForegroundProperty,
 Value = Brushes.LightGray
};

var borderThicknessSetter = new Setter()
{
 Property = Button.BorderThicknessProperty,
 Value = new Thickness(0)
};

var isEnabledTrigger = new Trigger()
{
 Property = Button.IsEnabledProperty,
 Value = false
 //Setters = { foregroundSetter, borderThicknessSetter }
};
isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(foregroundSetter);
isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(borderThicknessSetter);

var style = new Style();
style.Triggers.Add(isEnabledTrigger);

var pdfButton = new Button()
{
 Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
 Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0),
 Height = 18,
 Width = 20,
 Content = "PDF",
 FontSize = 9,
 FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold,
 Foreground = Brushes.Red,
 BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
 Background = Brushes.Transparent,
 ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "Create PDF of training day." },
 Command = CreatePdfCommand,
 CommandParameter = newTab,
 Style = style
};
```

Comment: I resolved by putting my style in a resource dictionary, before that I tried using the TextElement.ForegroundProperty, which also didn't work. So I still don't know why I coludn't get it to work. My solution seems like the hard way to do it, but what else is new when using WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assigned local value for Foreground property (`Foreground = Brushes.Red`). After that style trigger may be triggered but a Foreground setter from trigger will be ignored because local value has more weight (it is called  [Dependency Property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-7.0))

to fix that behavior set normal Foreground value via style setter:

```
var foregroundNormalSetter = new Setter()
{
 Property = Button.ForegroundProperty,
 Value = Brushes.Red
};

var foregroundSetter = new Setter()
{
 Property = Button.ForegroundProperty,
 Value = Brushes.LightGray
};

var borderThicknessSetter = new Setter()
{
 Property = Button.BorderThicknessProperty,
 Value = new Thickness(0)
};

var isEnabledTrigger = new Trigger()
{
 Property = Button.IsEnabledProperty,
 Value = false
 //Setters = { foregroundSetter, borderThicknessSetter }
};
isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(foregroundSetter);
isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(borderThicknessSetter);

var style = new Style();
style.Setters.Add(foregroundNormalSetter);
style.Triggers.Add(isEnabledTrigger);

var pdfButton = new Button()
{
 Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
 Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0),
 Height = 18,
 Width = 20,
 Content = "PDF",
 FontSize = 9,
 FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold,
 //Foreground = Brushes.Red,
 BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
 Background = Brushes.Transparent,
 ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "Create PDF of training day." },
 Command = CreatePdfCommand,
 CommandParameter = newTab,
 Style = style
};
```

Comment: Thank you for educating me, it is greatly appreciated.